# Openlayers 5 Display different Popup informations for different layers on the same map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

im using `OpenLayers 5` to display two different layers on the same map. I can see both Markers on the Map with different icons. The code below writes in the popup of one layer. Now my question is: how can i display different Infos on the Popup for each specific layer. For example when the mouse is over the first icon the popup should contain the name of the first layer and when it is over the second different icon it shows the name of the second layer.

 I assume i should use `map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel, function (layer1))` or something like this but im facing problems right there

```
//display the pop with on mouse over event
map.on('pointermove', function (event) {

    const features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel);
    
    if (features.length > 0 ) {  
        var coordinate = event.coordinate;
        
        //get the infos that are going to be displayed in the Pop-up window;
        const layerOneName = features[0].get('vehName');

        // text written inside the popup
        content.innerHTML = '<b>'+layerOneName +'</b>';
        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
    }
});
```

Comment: The Popup content should be based on the layer name

Answer (score 1):

If you use `forEachFeatureAtPixel` use can add a layer filter function and use that to set the layer

```
map.on('pointermove', function (event) {

    let layer;
    const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
      event.pixel,
      function (feature) {
        return feature;
      },
      { 
        layerFilter: function (candidate) {
          layer = candidate;
          return true;
        }
      }
    );
    
    if (feature) {  
        var coordinate = event.coordinate;
        
        //get the infos that are going to be displayed in the Pop-up window;
        const layerOneName = feature.get('vehName');

        // text written inside the popup
        content.innerHTML = '<b>'+layerOneName +'</b>';
        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
    }

});
```

Comment: How can i get the layer Name then?. For example if the mouse is over the layer1 then the Popup should contain `layerOneName` but if the mouse is over the layer2 and then `layerTwoName` should be written in the Popup

Comment: If you have set up the layers with a name property `layer.get('name')`

Comment: Still getting same results as my previous code. One Icon has correct infos, the second one is undefined. I think your code is missing something that indicates the mouse is over which layer (which what i actually need). I believe that `content.innerHTML` should be used twice, one for each icon?